# Using htmlspecialchars within mysqli_stmt_bind_result()

Tags: mysqli, prepared-statement, xss

Can `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` be used within `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`?

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,htmlspecialchars($var1));
```

Or better yet... If I am already using `htmlspecialchars` to echo form values, would inserting the validated values eliminate the need to use `htmlspecialchars` again in `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` before outputting onto page?

```
//if passes input validation from form...//
  $var1 = htmlentities($_POST['var1']);

//in prepared statement, binding value to be used in page...//
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$var1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No to the first question, and no to the second question.

You can't bind params or results to a non-lvalue. The argument for binding must be a variable that can be a PHP reference. The return value of a function does not qualify.

You shouldn't process content with htmlentities() *before* inserting into the database, because it will store literal html entities like `&amp;` as text in the database. If you forget that you did this, and process the content with htmlentities() again after fetching it from the database, it'll be double-encoded. Also if you decide to send that content from the database to another output (like a file or an email), it would be inappropriate to have it html entity encoded.

The better practice is to store plain text in the database, and use htmlentities() only as a last step as you echo it to HTML output.

Comment: So the input would be:
`mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$_POST['var1']);`
And the output would be:
`mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$var1);
$var1 = htmlspecialchars($var1);`, rather than
`mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,htmlspecialchars($var1));`